# How to request permissions to track events on android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, event-tracking

I have a react native app and I need to integrate 3rd platforms that track user activity in app (events like facebook sdk, branch.io etc) or send notifications to my app. For other permission required in my app, I have this in the manifest and I'm displaying a dialog to the user:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I can't seem to find information on how to request permission to track events or send push notification on android? Is there a specific permission type? Api level is 31. Any advise is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To ask Permission for android please follow the Documentation.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid.

on Permission Granted you can send a push notification if you want.

Comment: this documentation doesn't provide any information about events tracking permissions on android.

Comment: for tracking events you'll have to work with third-party packages or if you've knowledge of Native Technologies then you can take support from Native Modules